# Is it a bad practice to pass props to local state initial value and how to do it properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Total newbie, hope it's clear enough. Thanks!

I am trying to update a form in a child component and save the changes to global state. The global state is a deep nested json.

```
      {'userData':
        ['item':
        'education':{
          'school': 'school1';
          'major': 'major1';}
        'education':{
          'school': 'school2';
          'major': 'major2';}
         ]
}}
```

The child component is a form that depends on which item is picked from a dropdown list in the parent form.

I wanted to achieve the following:

1. Pre-populate values in my form field value for the chosen item in the nested json list, for example

```
'education':{
          'school': 'school1';
          'major': 'major1';}
```

2. Modify the global state based on the fields updated in the child form. 
   globalContext is where the global context is defined.

```
const [data, setData] = useContext(globalContext)
const [school, setSchool] = useState('')
const [degree, setDegree] = useState('')

const handleSubmit = (props) => {
    let tmpList = data.user1.userData;

    function findElement(arr, propValue) {
          for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
            if (arr[i].major.concat(' at ', arr[i].school) === propValue)
              return arr[i];}

    var filtered = findElement(tmpList, props)

    filtered.push({school, degree})
       setData({...data,
//                 user1: {
//                     ...data.user1,
//                     userData: filtered
//                     }})
    }
```

I have the problem that if the field is not touched by the user, it will be empty, because it's initial state is empty. 
If I use props as the initial state, it's an infinite loop. 
Also sounds bad practice.

Comment: [props as initial state is anti-pattern](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e)